# Arduino IDE on Fedora

Tags: arduino-ide, linux, fedora

I'm using [Fedora_21_MATE.img](http://sourceforge.net/projects/berryboot/files/os_images/Fedora_21_MATE.img/download) on a Raspberry Pi. Installing the Arduino IDE 1.0.6 using these commands, taken from [Arduino On Pi](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-On-Pi/). Those instructions are for Raspbian, I assume, so changing for Fedora, `apt-get` to `yum`:

```
sudo yum install arduino
```

One waits and `arduino` installs. One can then run the Arduino IDE from the Fedora GUI menu, and it loads - after moaning about the user has to be a member of the `dialout` and `lock` groups. This is easily resolved by adding the user to the required groups, using the control panel.

However, trying to compile anything, i.e. `blink`, in the IDE, gives me the following error:

```
avr-g++: error trying to exec cc1plus: execvp: No such file or directory
```

In verbose mode, little additional information is offered.

```
Arduino: 1.0.6 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Uno"
avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=106 -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /tmp/build6314348775898760987.tmp/Blink.cpp -o /tmp/build6314348775898760987.tmp/Blink.cpp.o 
avr-g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

The file in question, `cc1plus`, is actually present in the filesystem:

```
[piebody@berrybody ~]$ locate cc1plus
/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/cc1plus
/usr/libexec/gcc/avr/4.9.2/cc1plus
[piebody@berrybody ~]$
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't run "out of the box"? Do I need to modify any environment variables, and if so, which ones and with what exactly? I assume my `PATH` environment variable needs fixing, but is there any environment variable specific to `avr-g++` that needs changing?

I appreciate that this is probably a simple UNIX paths issue, and that the question may be more suited to SE: Unix & Linux.

Comment: Can you post the verbose build output?

Comment: Could you try this again with Fedora 23? I just tested it, and it works for me out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two issues:

- Getting the IDE to fully function when launched from the command
  line, and;
- Getting the IDE to fully function (i.e. compile) when launched from
  the Fedora GUI menu.

I have found a solution if I run the Arduino IDE from the command line, by adding the path to  one of the `cc1plus` binaries to the `PATH` environment variable:

```
[piebody@berrybody ~]$ PATH=${PATH}:/usr/libexec/gcc/avr/4.9.2
[piebody@berrybody ~]$ export PATH
[piebody@berrybody ~]$ arduino&
```

However, if I launch the Arduino IDE from the Fedora application menu, and then try to compile a sketch, it still can't locate `cc1plus`. Maybe the `PATH` needs to be added in my `.profile`, or some other mechanism, to get an application launched from the Fedora menu to see the path?<sup>1</sup>

Yet, even with the command line launch, it still does not finish compiling.  I now get the following error when the IDE attempts to compile:

```
In file included from Blink.ino:18:0:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:23:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlib.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

In verbose mode

```
Arduino: 1.0.6 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Uno"
avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=106 -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /tmp/build1210300884764677972.tmp/Blink.cpp -o /tmp/build1210300884764677972.tmp/Blink.cpp.o 
In file included from Blink.ino:18:0:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:23:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlib.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

I assume that this is another `PATH` issue. One that relates to the path to the Arduino libraries, or [`libc`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=441404) libraries.

After reading [can't locate avr libraries](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=48232.0)<sup>2</sup>, I can't see why `avr-g++` is not picking up the `avr` directory in the `/usr` directory.

The actual path to `stdlib.h` is `/usr/avr/include/stdlib.h`

The output of `avr-gcc` (and `avr-g++`) shows `--prefix=/usr`

The Arduino IDE preference file (`~/.arduino/preference.txt`) shows the line

```
last.ide.1.0.6.hardwarepath=/usr/share/arduino/hardware
```

**Linking the includes**

If I manually link some header files to where the compiler actually is looking, then it works (until `avr-gcc` needs a header that I have not linked to):

```
cd /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino
sudo ln -s /usr/avr/include/stdlib.h stdlib.h
sudo ln -s /usr/avr/include/string.h string.h
sudo ln -s /usr/avr/include/math.h math.h
```

but I can not do this for *every* header file, it is ridiculous. There must be a way of linking to `/usr/avr` from `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino`. I have tried linking the parent directories `/usr/avr` and `/usr/avr/include`, at various points along the directory hierarchy of `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino`, but none of those seem to work.

**Copying the include directory**

After reading [default include file path?](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/default-include-file-path), and running `avr-cpp -v` I saw that the default `#include` search path was

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/include
 /bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/include-fixed
End of search list.
```

From this, I could see that `avr-cpp` was searching in `/lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/include`. I examined, and compared, the contents of `/lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/include` with `/usr/avr/include` and they held similar (the same) files, except `/lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/include` was a subset, that is to say that it was missing the required files.

I ended up copying the `/usr/avr/include` directory, which contains the required header files (`stdlid.h` etc., to which I had linked previously), and replacing the original `include` directory, in the directory where `avr-gcc` seemed to be looking, which was in its own directory location `/lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/`.

```
cd /lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/
mv include include.old
cp -r /usr/avr/include .
```

Then the Arduino compiler seemed to work, until it then gave an assembler error:

```
Assembler messages
Error: unrecognized option -mmcu=avr5
```

This is an issue with `avr-as`.

I will update as I resolve these issues.

---

<sup>1</sup> I eventually resolved this by creating a script in `/usr/bin` (where the `arduino` binary was located) called `arduino.launch` which contains the `PATH` settings and a call to `arduino`:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/libexec/gcc/avr/4.9.2
export PATH
arduino
```

setting it to be executable with `chmod +x arduino.launch`. Then I edited the properties of the Fedora Arduino launch icon, by right-clicking on the icon and selecting **Properties**, and changed the **Command** entry from `arduino` to `arduino.launch`.

However, there must be a better way of doing this, as this seems to be a bit of a hack.

<sup>2</sup> Other posts [1](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=49652.0), [2](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=86852.0) and [3](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=52129.0)) that I have read, apart from providing useful paths to investigate, merely suggest reinstalling. However, as bone headed as I may seem, there must be a way of linking up what is already on the file system (everything is there - just in the "wrong" place), such that compiles work as they should.