# How to install Arduino IDE on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberrypi

How do you install the Arduino IDE on the Raspberry Pi running an ARM version of Ubuntu or Raspbian? There doesn't seem to be any [official ARM release](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/OldSoftwareReleases#00xx). Both distros have an "arduino" package in their standard repos, but it only includes an ancient 1.0 version that's missing a lot of features.

Comment: have you tried downloading the linux 32 bit version it from arduino.cc? what happens?

Comment: Yes, I thought that might work too, but it's compiled for the i386 architecture so it gives me an error when I try to run it on the RPi. Apparently, i386 and 32-bit ARM are not compatible.

Comment: The IDE is java, so you might just need to replace the avr-gcc stuff with its arm version

Comment: The IDE is indeed written in Java, but build with Ant, which results in a not cross-platform startup file. I do think it should be possible compiling Arduino yourself on the rpi. Lookup a tutorial on ant builds on the rpi and clone the sources from the github repository.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I have it _sort of_ running on Fedora on a Pi, see [Arduino IDE on Fedora](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13692/arduino-ide-on-fedora/). I've had a few (path) issues, to which my post will attest, which I am sure are surmountable.

Comment: It's included in raspbian. Also in lemakers raspbian for bananapi.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino at http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/Raspbian recommends:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arduino
```

but indeed warns that the version is old:

> Note: This will install an old version of Arduino, and may not support
>   some of the newer boards. You can not download a newer version from
>   the website, because there is no ARM version. -- [Arduino wiki on Raspbian](http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/Raspbian)

Looking at the raspbian respository at http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/arduino/ currently lists 1.0.5

There are folks working newer versions of Arduino for ARM at https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/3334 but it isn't finished yet.

Comment: why on earth would you like to run on the Pi? It's hideously slow. A ten-year-old intel machine is faster.